# Running an autosys job for more than an hour

Tags: autosys

for a job running from 17.30-19.00, should the timing will be 30,35,40,45,50,55,59,5,10,15,20,25?
like starting from 30,35...reaching till 18.00 and then restart again? Thanks!

Comment: 59 should be 0, where it's 18:00. You're not running at 17:59. It should be 50, 55, (18:0)0, 5, 10. (And this is not a programming question, so it's really not on-topic here.)

Comment: thanks a lot...I saw other autosys question here, so I posted mine :)

Comment: The existence of previous questions does not mean a new question is on-topic. There are many questions here that have existed for years, before there were other more appropriate [se] sites. However, that's irrelevant in this case, because your question has absolutely nothing to do with autosys.